# Haskell: filter list from minimum and maximum

Tags: parsing, haskell, filter

I am trying to remove the maximum and minimum out of a list.

```
filter (/= minimum [1,2,3,4] && /= maximum [1,2,3,4] ) [1,2,3,4]
```

Unfortunately whenever I try to do this I get an parse error on input "\="
Does anybody know what is the reason behind this error and how I can solve it?

Comment: You did not ask for this, but you should use a `let` or `where` for binding minimum and maximum outside of the filter -- doing the filter as above will likely lead to min/max being recomputed for each list element, leading to quadratic complexity instead of linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix

```
filter (\x -> x /= minimum [1,2,3,4] && x /= maximum [1,2,3,4]) [1,2,3,4]
```

as a function

```
removeMinMax xs = filter (\x -> x /= minimum xs && x /= maximum xs) xs
```

pointfree (the filter)

```
removeMinMax xs = filter (not.flip elem [minimum xs, maximum xs]) xs
```

Comment: Great, I got my algorithm working now. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

```
&& :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
/= minimum [1,2,3,4], /= maximum [1,2,3,4] :: Int -> Bool
```

You've tried to link two `Int -> Bool` functions with a `Bool -> Bool -> Bool` operator. You'd need to wrap them in a lambda (and apply the missing `Int`) or put in an array and use `all`.

Comment: Thank you for you explication. Now I finally know why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

@josejuan already gave a point free style. In addition to that I would go with this :

```
f xs = filter (flip notElem $ [maximum, minimum] <*> pure xs) xs
```

With applicatives it becomes more flexible, Say you also want to filter elments that equals to first and last element from list :

```
f xs = filter (flip notElem $ [maximum, minimum, head, last] <*> pure xs) xs

> f [2,1,5,3,42]
[5,3]
```